# How can I prove this?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I want to show this but I have problem with where I should start .

For two interpretation function $I$,$J$ , we define $I \le J$ when for every atom $p$ we have $I(p) \le J(p)$.We define proposition A is increasing if for two interpretation function $I,J$ that $I \le J$ we have $I(A)\le J(A)$.

Now I want to prove this:

Proposition A is increasing if only and if for every atom $p$ and two proposition $B$ and $C$ that $B \models C$ we have $A[p/B] \models A[p/C]$

Comment: What have you tried? Where do you get stuck? Do you have any intuition for why it ought to be true?

Comment: If I suppose A is increasing it means for every two interpretation $I \le J$ I have $I(A) \le J(A)$ and suppose two proposition $B,C$ that $I(B) = 1 \rightarrow I(C) = 1$ for every interpretation $I$, now I must prove that for every interpretation $I$ ,$I(A[p/B]) = 1 \rightarrow I(A[p/C]) = 1$.

Comment: I don't have any idea how can I achieve this.

Comment: It's better not to put the details in the comments. Please edit your question instead and explain what you have tried already